# Minecraft Log in Troubles

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I can't log into my account. I put in my username and it tells me it doesn't exist so I click forgot username and put in my email. When I checked my email it had a completely different unpaid for name. I have no clue what I did to make it like that and any information would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think we will be able to help, you will probably need to get in touch with Mojang about this (though someone may come along with a solution)

Comment: Have you registered with multiple email adresses?

Comment: This isn't really a gaming question, this is something that you should email to mojang support.

Answer (score 2):

If you use multiple email addresses, try searching your email archive for letters from Mojang to make sure you are entering the email you registered with. If that doesn't work, or if you're sure you're entering the correct email, your only option is to [contact support](https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/emails/new?ref=footer).